# Wordpress loses database connection intermittedly

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a server hosting a wordpress website that will initially display a page with full functionality fine but at random intervals pages will fail to load saying unable to establish mysql database connection and to check the wp-config.php file.

I have checked the login information in it and is correct so I am unsure as to why it continues to fail seemingly without cause, any suggestions would be appreciated as right now I have to reboot the sever often

Comment: lokk at the error log of mysql if there is a problem listed. What you can do is log the connection errors to see if there is a patterm( like every hour or all 10 minutes.

Comment: Thank you that helped me find an error "Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed." followed by out of memory, I think I need to create a swap file to handle the overflow

Comment: This sounds like an issue with either your database or the connection between your website hosting and database server. Either way it doesn’t sound like a Wordpress issue. Check the logs as nbk suggests, and also check your hosting server logs in case something shows there e.g. connection errors, and I suggest then asking on either the DBA or SuperUser stackexchange sites as StackOverflow is for programming questions so you might get more specific help there

Comment: You must have added your comment while I was typing mine and I didn't see it. As it’s definitely a db problem, I suggest asking on DBA.stackexchange.com about the error you found - its more suited to that site plus you’re more likely to find more db expertise there :)